# How to make other buttons on same div inherit the height size of a much bigger button?

Tags: html, css

Using HTML with CSS.

On a single div, I have three buttons each with different class (border style) coded in CSS. I made the buttons behave where their widths are fixed while the height changes size depending on the text length.

The problem I have is, when one button change size (height), the other buttons does not follow or does not inherit the same height the div is adjusted too.

Here is my code in HTML:

```
  <div class="container-1020-Apx">

        <button type="button" class="btn-styleLT">The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy rabbit because it is not paying attention to it's mother who cried wolf. </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn-styleCT"> middle </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn-styleRT"> right </button>
  </div>
```

Here is my code in CSS:

```
 .container-1020-Apx {
    margin:auto;
    text-align: left;
    width:1020px;
    min-height: 30px;
    background-color: White;
    display:block;
 }

 .btn-styleLT{
    border : solid 2px #170417;
    border-radius : 20px 0px 0px 0px ;
    moz-border-radius : 0px 20px 0px 0px ;
    font-size : 16px;
    color : #f4f6f7;
    padding : 4px 18px;
    width: 422px;
    background : #000000;
    background : -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#000000), color-stop(100%,#353535));
    background : -moz-linear-gradient(top, #000000 0%, #1f3b08 100%);
    background : -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000000 0%, #1f3b08 100%);
    background : -o-linear-gradient(top, #000000 0%, #1f3b08 100%);
    background : -ms-linear-gradient(top, #000000 0%, #1f3b08 100%);
    background : linear-gradient(top, #000000 0%, #1f3b08 100%);
    filter : progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#1a0d1a',GradientType=0 );
    min-height: 20px;
    max-height: inherit;
 }

 .btn-styleRT{
    border : solid 2px #170417;
    border-radius : 0px 20px 0px 0px ;
    ... <almost same content>
    min-height: 20px;
    max-height: inherit;
 }

 .btn-styleCT{
    border : solid 2px #170417;
    font-size : 16px;
    color : #f4f6f7;
    padding : 4px 18px;
    width:167px;
    background : #000000;
    ... <almost same content> 
    min-height: 20px;
    max-height: inherit;
 }

 .btn-styleLT:hover,
 .btn-styleLT:focus,
 .btn-styleLT:active,
 .btn-styleLT.active {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #3276b1;
    border-color: #285e8e;
 }

 .btn-styleRT:hover,
  ... <same>
    border-color: #285e8e;
 }

 .btn-styleCT:hover,
 ... <same>
    border-color: #285e8e;
 }
```

Any ideas? I was thinking to provide individual div for each button, but if there is a work-around without doing so, that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use display:table and display:table-cell to achieve what you want.

here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vtajZ/293/

html:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"><button type="button" class="btn-styleLT">The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy rabbit because it is not paying attention to it's mother who cried wolf. </button></div>
    <div class="child"><button type="button" class="btn-styleCT"> middle </button></div>
    <div class="child"><button type="button" class="btn-styleRT"> right </button></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
*{
    box-sizing:content-box;
}
.parent {
    display: table;
    position:relative;
}
.child {
    display: table-cell;
}

.btn-styleLT{
    border : solid 2px #170417;
    border-radius : 20px 0px 0px 0px ;
    moz-border-radius : 0px 20px 0px 0px ;
    font-size : 16px;
    color : #f4f6f7;
    padding : 4px 18px;
    width: 422px;
    background : #000000;
    background : -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#000000), color-stop(100%,#353535));
    background : -moz-linear-gradient(top, #000000 0%, #1f3b08 100%);
    background : -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000000 0%, #1f3b08 100%);
    background : -o-linear-gradient(top, #000000 0%, #1f3b08 100%);
    background : -ms-linear-gradient(top, #000000 0%, #1f3b08 100%);
    background : linear-gradient(top, #000000 0%, #1f3b08 100%);
    filter : progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#1a0d1a',GradientType=0 );
    min-height: 20px;
    max-height: inherit;
 }

 .btn-styleRT{
    border : solid 2px #170417;
    border-radius : 0px 20px 0px 0px ;
    ... <almost same content>
    min-height: 20px;
    max-height: inherit;
 }

 .btn-styleCT{
    border : solid 2px #170417;
    font-size : 16px;
    color : #f4f6f7;
    padding : 4px 18px;
    width:167px;
    background : #000000;
    ... <almost same content> 
    min-height: 20px;
    max-height: inherit;
 }
.btn-styleCT,.btn-styleRT{
    height: 100%;
}
.btn-styleCT{
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
}
.parent button{
    margin:0px;
}
```

Comment: Yup that's what I was thinking of doing when I said "I was thinking to provide individual div for each button".

I hope you don't mind if I wait for some more days to see what others has to offer, maybe without the divs.

Comment: you can easily do the same without the additional divs by setting the buttons themselves to "display: table-cell" and "vertical-align: middle"
here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vtajZ/295/